# Run a Rmarkdown file and push to gh-pages using circle CI

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, circleci

I've got a project on github with an Rmarkdown file. I want to build it and push the html file to gh-pages using circle ci. I don't understand how to write my circle ci configuration file : https://github.com/SGMAP-AGD/panorama/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Comment: This is probably a better question for CircleCI Discuss: https://discuss.circleci.com/